# How can I add a TypeConverter for a particular type?

Tags: c#, typeconverter

In C#, if I have a property of type object, and I know the Type of the object, how can I display the default TypeConverter for the property?

Here is some code:

```
private Type _valueType { get; set; }
public Type ValueType
{
    get
    {
        return _valueType;
    }
    set
    {
        _valueType = value;
    }
}
private object _value { get; set; }
public object Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value;
    }
    set
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

In the above code, if the ValueType property is a bool, how can I display the default TypeConverter for a bool on the Value property?

This is for a PropertyGrid object's SelectedObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the code needed.

Here it is:

```
public TypeConverter GetValueTypeConverter()
{
    TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(_valueType);
    return typeConverter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that you can achieve the effect you're looking for [through the use of Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
class GenericsExample<T>{

    private T _value { get; set; }
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

An instance of your class can then be created with a given type (for instance bool), and variables of any that type can be returned from your class:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var genericsExample = new GenericsExample<bool>();
        genericsExample.Value = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Value is " + genericsExample.Value);
    }
}
```

Is this along the lines of what you where looking for?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.booleanconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I have found a much simpler method to do what is required without using generics.